# kartik Select2 widget. How to change color of choices?

Tags: jquery-select2, yii2

I am curious how to change the hover color of choices in `kartik select2 widget`?[image]

I use `yii2`. My `app` renders following `code` for `dropdown` element of `select2`:

```
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

But there is nothing inside it. So which classes are responsible for choices `hover` e.t.c?

Answer (score 1):

this CSS should do the job (if you was asking for the Category3 dark blue element)

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
    background-color: lime;
}
```

[image: Select2 Yii2 change (hovered / highlighted) item]

Answer (score 0):

This is how `kartik select2` creates the DOM. Above the `<span>` you will find `<select>` tag.

```
<select id="w13" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="kv-type-01" data-s2-options="s2options_d6851687" data-krajee-select2="select2_f12d7f7f" style="display:none" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="">Select a type...</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
    <option value="5">Fifth</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--krajee select2-container--below select2-container--open select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-w13-container" aria-owns="select2-w13-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-w13-result-9vjw-5">
  <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-w13-container">
    <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select a type ...</span>
  </span>
  <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
  </span>
</span>
```

Applying your hover effect on the `<select>` options tag will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried   `select option:hover { background-color: lime; } `. Does not work.